# How to design Voting System that handles a large amount of votes but at the same time we can trace back who vote what?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to build a system that allows user to vote up & down the product. Each user can only vote up/down 1 time only for a product, but that user can vote as many products as they want. I am using MYSQL DB.

So, here is what i am thinking. I will create a simple voting table that has 3 columns (userID, productID, vote). Vote column only have `+1` or `-1` value.

```
userID - productID - vote
122544  5454545  1
122544  5454546  1
122544  5454547  -1
122545  5454546  -1
122545  5454547  -1
```

By designing like this we can know who votes what. But there is a serious problem. That is if we have millions votes a day, then the Voting table will grow really quickly and start to eat up DB space quickly & that could make DB slow down. Also, i have to use unsigned long type, & that also makes the DB bigger.

So, how to design Voting System that handles a large amount of votes but at the same time we can trace back who vote what?

I think Facebook voting system is good, i wish i can build a system like that, but do you know how to?

Comment: Databases are designed to handle large quantities of data like this. It shouldn't be a problem. Make sure you index the fields that you need to search on.

Comment: If million votes a day, you should implement sharding counters. I know  how that is implemented in [appengine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters), but the idea would probably help your time. You please also let us know the server language you are using.

Comment: A million records is going to a few MB.  Space shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Let's assume 1000000 votes a day. One record should be 2 X int + 1 small int, it is, say 6b..X 1000000 6mb/day, so after a year, it will be.......about 2G (now, I did big generalization, but you have the picture).

Comment: @Malimovka: so what datatype should i use for Vote column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a three-column table as you have shown in your question. Presumably you want to report out the votes for particular products.

So, define your table as

```
productID  BIGINT
userID     BIGINT
vote       INT
```

The primary key should be the compound key (productID, userID). This will serve to enforce your no-duplicate-votes rule.

You should also define an index on (productID, vote) to speed up the query of how many votes have been cast for a particular product. This is called a covering index.

```
    SELECT productID, 
           SUM(vote) AS votes
      FROM vote_table
     WHERE productID = ?whatever
  GROUP BY productID
```

Don't worry about the performance for now, just get the application working. This kind of table is extremely efficient.  Disk space and RAM are far cheaper than your labor, and they are cheaper than a delay getting your project completed and into the hands of users.  If you do in fact end up with billions of votes, you can figure out how to scale up your application appropriately.

Comment: seem this is right answer, thank you. Life is short.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind this is a highly abstract answer.  The database likely cannot be optimized. You can only be so efficient and the system described above seems to be about as efficient as it gets.  You'll simply have to understand that the database will grow with the votes. The only thing based on what you described would be to use something other than a long type.

As for quickly mapping votes to people, you can set up multiple tables (such as one for each 1000 members) so your system can quickly jump to the appropriate table.  To further optimize mapping votes to people, you can synthesize the vote id based on the user id.  For example, if a user id is 400439, create a vote id with an extra couple digits, starting at 4004390 and incrementing up from there (next would be 4004391, then 4004392, etc.).